# Download .click package

Tags: application-development, downloads, click-packages

I've had some problem with my computer and, sadly, I lost all .click packages I've developed.

I would like to download them but I don't know how.

In myapps page on ubuntu.com ( https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/ ) upload the .click packages and also put them on the market  is very easy but seems there is no way to download them...

I don't need to install the package I'm only interested to the file so I could open it using

```
ar x file_name
```

Comment: .click? What? That isn't even for any software.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to download the last version .click package directly from the "manage version" in the myapps.developer.ubuntu.com
The procedure is: 
login
enter in the desired package review,
click on the version number (there is a green box icon in its left)
click on the link at the "download" line.